# How force iFrame open all links stay in the iFrame?

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm hosting an iFrame and it seems like when a link points to external domains it loads it on the main window and not in the iFrame.
Is there a way to force the links to be opened in the same iFrame?

Notice: I can add anything I want to the page loaded in the iFrame (using Chrome extension).

I tried adding:

```
<base target="_parent" />
```

But it didn't do any good...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check Headers of your external domain page. If `X-Frame-Options` Header is set to `DENY`, browser ignores loading content to **iframe** or **frame set** and loads in main frame of browser.

```
Regardless of the site attempts the page cannot be displayed in a frame.
```

### Your Code

`<base target="_parent" />`   is used for Loading the result into the parent browsing context of the current one. If there is no parent, this option behaves the same way as `_self`, so it can not solve your problem

Use 
`<base target="myframe">` instead where `myframe` is name of your iframe.

```
<iframe width="200" height="200" name="myframe"></iframe>
```

## Demonstration

Look for server headers for loading pages

```
<html>

    <head>
        <base target="myframe">
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="hi.html">Base</a>
        <a href="bye.html">A Tag</a>
        <iframe width="200" height="200" name="myframe"></iframe>
    </body>

</html>
```

## References

- [X-Frame-Options Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)

Comment: I'm not sure how that help. I have an iFrame loaded already and clicking on link *in* the iFrame causes the page to be loaded in the main frame and on in the internal iFrame.

Comment: Thank you great answer: "Use  <base target="myframe"> instead where myframe is name of your iframe." works perfectly as you'd expect. I wasn't aware that you could use an element as the target.