# Leave the original page after clicking on a link in an iframe

Tags: iframe, break

I wanted to know how to leave the original page after clicking on a link in an iframe?

If I click on a link in iframe webpages, the link loads in that iframe element instead of leaving the original page.

Any sugg?

Comment: What did you try so far?  Please show your code.

Comment: It will surely help.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14405114/1734707

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
window.top.location = 'MY_URL';
```

from within the iframe, offcourse.